# 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'UserDB.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting an error while saving data in SQL Server using ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework. The error says it cannot insert data that has a null primary key. I have already set the `IsIdentity` to auto-increment by 1.

This is the code:

```
public ActionResult Index(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        if (user.UserId != 0) 
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        else
            user.IsActive = true;

        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Please share the table creation statement and insert statement that you're attempting to execute.

Comment: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Users'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (0).

Comment: Hard to help you with this.  You claim one thing, your error claims another.  Clearly the exception is telling you the truth.

Comment: Please include the table definition, the `create table ...` statement. Also, please share the exact error.

Answer (score 1):

This is an SQL thing. If you have a table with columns `ID` and `Name`, where `ID` is the primary key, with accompanying identity settings and `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` constraints, the insert statements **must** look like this:

```
INSERT INTO [table] (name) values ('Vivek')
```

This will automatically handle the ID column. This, however, will fail:

```
INSERT INTO [table] (ID, name) values (NULL, 'Vivek')
```

It's trying to tell the database you want the value of the `ID` column to be `NULL`. Of course this fails, because of the `NOT NULL` constraint. It is different than the first option, where the database was allowed to use the identity to set the value for the `ID` column.

So now on to the (presumably) C# code. There is a `User` object here which does not have an `ID` value yet, because you're just creating it. Probably this `User` type (which is not shared, so I can only guess) has a simple `int` value for `ID`, and this int has not been initialized (meaning the value is `default(int)`, which is `0`). Now you go to insert the record. Linq will generate an SQL statement similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO [table] (ID, name) values (0, 'Vivek')
```

But somewhere in the past you've run the same code, with the same `0` value for the ID, and so there's already another record in the table with that ID value. This fails the UNIQUE constraint, and SQL Server (rightly) rejects the SQL statement.

To fix this, we'll *start* by changing the ID value on this model to use an `int?` type. I know you probably don't want that everywhere, so you can actually use a different class here (`NewUser`) if it helps you. This will allow a truly empty (NULL) value for the ID column in the generated SQL.

But now we have a new problem: we end up with an insert like my second example. We see this isn't enough; we need tell linq to not use that column in the generated SQL at all. You can do this by removing the ID property from the special `NewUser` class entirely.

But we can do still better. Linq allows us to use something called [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) to decorate properties with information that influence the generated SQL. You can do that here to tell it how to handle the ID column:

```
[Column(DbType="INT NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
public int ID {get; set;}
```

And *this* can go with the existing `User` class, without the need to create a whole new type.

Comment: DbType,IsPrimaryKey,IsDbGenerated Namespaces are not able to add in the class